# Can't seem to remove background from container, parallax scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4, parallax

trying to do the freecodecamp front end project 2 but i am stuck on this problem for hours, been searching forever - https://i.stack.imgur.com/N84L0.jpg

Text placed over the parallax will create a box around it with white space. I wanted the background to be transparent.

jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/n6ba43vz/

Live - http://51.15.81.36/

```
      <div class="container" style="background-color:#DCDCDC overflow: hidden; position: relative">
    <hr>
      <div style="color:#ddd;background-color:#282E34;text-align:center;padding:50px 80px;text-align: justify;">
        <h5>Front-End Developer and UX/UI designer, with practical experience in project management, branding strategy, and creative direction; devoted to functional programming and information architecture.</h5>
          <hr>
          <h3>Web Developer - User Experience Designer - Graphic Artist</h3>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Cant't figure out the problem...

Comment: maybe make the parralax `position: fixed;` and use top/right/bottom/top value to stretch it

Comment: Don't think you understood what i meant, or i phrased it pretty bad. I want to get rid of the white background that overlaps the parralax image. But anyways, this one didn't work, since i assume that the container overlaps the parallax...

Comment: the issue is that you parralax isn't overlapping, there is no positioning used with it. It's simply under your content as a normal div [as i see in your fiddle and your site]

Comment: there is no `background-position: fixed;` you are looking as i said for `position:fixed`

Comment: so you are looking for the wrong issue, there is no background to remove, you need to simply make the parallax correctly

Comment: add this to your parralax `position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -2;` and see the result

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! I was already trying z-index before and etc but didn't help. So the background-position: fixed was the problem?

Comment: yes, background-position control the position of the background inside your element and you need to control the position of the element, so you have to simply use position ... and with top/left/right/bottom you stretch your element to take the needed space